# POST service parameter - FLASK

Tags: python, flask

This is what i get

```
b'{"data": "https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T03HPFD2P-F2RU2S4R0/scher7-om-14.52.47.png"}'
```

when i print my request data from a flask POST web service.

```
print(request.data)
```

But when i do `url = request.form.get('data', None)`
I get value of `url` variable `None`
Why?

Comment: what is `b` in this json data

Comment: How are you posting the data? Please include any relevant code, like html forms, curl/requests syntax, etc.

Comment: I am posting data using `req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})`

Comment: You should paramaterize your request like this: `req = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})` Then access it in your flask application as `request.json` -- The problem is your not submitting FORM data, therefore `request.form` will not have anything!

Comment: and how can i submit it?

Comment: What do you mean by "submit it" ?

Comment: you just said, that I am not submitting form data, but if that is the situation, then in my flask service,,,after receiving request, doing this `print(request.data)` should not print data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126237/discussion-between-sytech-and-guru).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you sent the request as follows:

```
req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

When sending json data, you should format the request in `requests` with the `json` parameter as follows:

```
req = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Further, in your flask app, you can access submitted json data via `request.json`

Because the content type is `application/json` -- it will not appear in `request.form` -- Data will appear in `request.form` when a request is received with an appropriate content type such as `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0):

What's the **Content-Type** header in your **POST** request?

As described in its [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request): **request.form** is a dict contains data parsed from POST or PUT form, while **request.data** contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with a mimetype Flask does not handle.

For the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask("Test")

@app.route("/ping", methods=['POST'])
def ping():
    print "Data: ", request.data
    print "Form: ", request.form
    return "pong"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7070, debug=False)
```

- Curl with default **Content-Type**, there's no data in **request.data**:

  ```
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: a/b" --data 'data=https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T03HPFD2P-F2RU2S4R0/schermafbeelding-2016-01-27-om-14.52.47.png' http://localhost:7070/ping
  ```

  Output:

  ```
   * Running on http://0.0.0.0:7070/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
   Data:
   Form:  ImmutableMultiDict([('data', u'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T03HPFD2P-F2RU2S4R0/schermafbeelding-2016-01-27-om-14.52.47.png')])
   127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016 21:40:41] "POST /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  ```
- But curl with a unknown **Content-Type** header, there's no data in **request.form**:

  ```
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: a/b" --data 'data=https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T03HPFD2P-F2RU2S4R0/schermafbeelding-2016-01-27-om-14.52.47.png' http://localhost:7070/ping
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Data:  data=https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T03HPFD2P-F2RU2S4R0/schermafbeelding-2016-01-27-om-14.52.47.png
  Form:  ImmutableMultiDict([])
  127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2016 21:43:52] "POST /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  ```

So if you want your form data in **request.form**, make sure the **Content-Type** is the one of those Flask can handle.